# LTSPICE Bridge Rectifier - Odd Output

Tags: rectifier, ltspice

I'm trying to simulate a simple full wave rectifier in LTSPICE. The output I am getting is not what I am expecting. In the picture below, the green line is the voltage output from the + terminal of the sine wave, the blue line is the - terminal of the sine wave and the red line is the output directly from the bridge rectifier (just prior to C1).

[image: LTSPICE Circuit and Output]

It looks to me as if there is a problem with the sine source, in that it's increasing. I've deleted the circuit several times and redrawn, and I've restarted the whole schematic file again several times. If I just place in a single sine source connected to ground and nothing, I get the expected output (cycling between +/- 34V) but as soon as I connect the - output to a circuit, it all goes crazy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a (possibly hidden) place to add series resistance in V1. Make sure that "Parasitic Properties" Series Resistance is set to 0, and I would suggest checking off "Make this information visible"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I found the setting for series resistance and it was blank. I added a 0 to see if that would change anything, but same output unfortunately.

Comment: Hint: If you go to:  LTspice \ Control Panel \ Waveforms   and left-click on the "Plot data with thick lines" box,  it'll make the plotted waveform very much more viewable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be displaying the differential voltage across V1 since it isn't ground referenced. The output (which is ground referenced) is behaving as expected. I don't think that waveform you are seeing makes sense though..

BTW, there is a (possibly hidden) place to add series resistance in V1. Make sure that "Parasitic Properties" Series Resistance is set to 0, and I would suggest checking off "Make this information visible".

Edit: This simulation behaves similarly when I simulate it, and it's due to the bottom end of the source floating around. If you connect a 100K resistor from the bottom end of the source to ground it does not affect the output voltage but the top of the source looks more like what I think you would expect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked - I'm unsure how it produced the initial graphs but by right clicking the - terminal of the source and selecting "mark reference", I get the correct sine output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Capacitance is too much higher which needs time to charge completely. Try a small value such as 500u, it will get a regular result.

[image]